# Ease switching from one display controller to the other

Tags: x11, hdmi

My laptop (a Dell M4800) provide 2 display controllers.
The default controller (i815) drives the LCD while the Radeon controller drives the HDMI output.
To activate HDMI output, I have to declare the Radeon as PrimaryGPU in xorg.conf/ and reboot.
I would like a way to automatically switch to i815 (thus LCD) if there's no monitor connected to HDMI connector.
That means switching from one controller to the other without rebooting.
Is that possible on a Debian 11?
Can I keep both controllers active?

Comment: You might be able to avoid reboot by using `xrandr` which can select the primary monitor.